# How to dismiss camera after barcode scanning

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to dismiss camera once barcode is scanned successfully and return the result back to previous `UIViewController`.

I have tried following code for camera dismiss but it is not working.

```
self.captureSession.stopRunning()  
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @ Ragini Are you using AVFoundation ?.. or some library ?..

Comment: I am using AVFoundation.

Comment: func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
You can use this delegate method

Comment: You might want to check the delegate method...

Comment: @Ragini it resolved?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani - No

Comment: @Ragini you could provide the full code so that we can find the bug?

Answer (score 2):

You have the `metadataOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` function:

> Informs the delegate that the capture output object emitted new
>   metadata objects.

Dismiss the camera inside that method:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, 
                   didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], 
                        from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with `DispatchQueue`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.captureSession.stopRunning()  
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```